# How do I make an explicit path take precendence over a named parameter when defining angularjs routes

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

In the following example both routes resolve to the detail.html template. How do I make the first route take precedence since it's defined explicitly and not as a named parameter?

```
$routeProvider.
             when('/about', {templateUrl: 'about.html'}).
             when('/:id', {templateUrl: 'details.html'});
```

Comment: First route should take precedence when you request localhost/#/about. The second route should fetch everything else (e.g. localhost/#/44, localhost/#/something). Can you show the actual URLs that you are trying to open.

Answer (score 0):

Stewie, you are correct. The first route takes precedent.